# Cannot install Flutter on MacOS Catalina

Tags: flutter, macos-catalina

I cannot install Flutter on my Mac running OSCatalina. I am following these instructions.

```
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path
```

I tried the terminal commands below. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
~ % echo 'export PATH="/Users/richard/Developer/flutter/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.zsc
~ % flutter --version
zsh: command not found: flutter
~ % echo 'export PATH="/Users/richard/Developer/flutter/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.zshrc
~ % flutter --version
zsh: command not found: flutter
~ % export PATH="$PATH:'pwd'/flutter/bin"
~ % which flutter
flutter not found
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your quotes are the wrong ones. It should be like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

Just do `echo $PATH` to see whether you see `/Users/richard/Developer/flutter/bin` in the list.

Comment: thanks. I double clicked on the .exe in the /bin and allowed it in settings / security and now it installs...